# Why Does PHP's Type Hinting Think My Class is a String?

Tags: php, oop, type-hinting

I'm working on a PHP class that I wrote. Its `setColour()` method typehints for an instance of another class of mine, `Colour`.

I'm doing this:

```
$colour = new Colour($updates->colour);
echo get_class($colour);
$product->setColour($colour);
```

As I'd expect, the get_class tells me that `$colour` is an instance of `domain\Colour`, but I then get an error when passing it to `setColour()`:

> Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to domain\Product::setColour() must be an instance of domain\Colour, string given,…

`Colour` looks like this:

```
<?php
namespace base\domain;

/**
 * Represents a colour.
 *
 **/
class Colour extends \base\domain\Enum {
const __default = self::NONE;

const NONE = NULL;
const BLACK = 'black';
const BLUE = 'blue';
const BRONZE = 'bronze';
const BROWN = 'brown';
const GOLD = 'gold';
const GREEN = 'green';
const GREY = 'grey';
const MULTICOLOURED = 'multicoloured';
const ORANGE = 'orange';
const PINK = 'pink';
const PURPLE = 'purple';
const RED = 'red';
const SILVER = 'silver';
const WHITE = 'white';
const YELLOW = 'yellow';

} // END class Colour
```

`Colour` extends a custom `Enum` type, which overrides `__toString()`, so I thought that might be causing the problem, but when I removing the `__toString()` implementation doesn't help.

Any thoughts you can offer would be much appreciated.

Comment: Weird. Is what you show above the literal code?

Comment: and what happens if you do `$product->setColour(new Colour($updates->colour));` ??

Comment: post the classes in question and it would be easier to help u out

Comment: @Pekka, yes the code is verbatim.

Comment: This works fine for me, not getting a warning. (snippet: http://pastebin.com/uh7DrFJE).  Which version are you using?

Comment: Can you show what the `Colour` class  looks like?

Comment: @pleasedontbelong, 
$product->setColour(new Colour($updates->colour)); causes the same error, I'm afraid.

Comment: Problem solved: it turns out that `setColour()` was also being called elsewhere, with a string. [FACEPALM]

Apologies for troubling you with this. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I make a test, i don't see any problems:

```
<?php

class Colour {

    private $name;

    public function __toString() {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function __construct($name) {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

}

class Product {

    public $colour;

    public function setColour(Colour $c) {
        $this->colour = $c;
    }

}

error_reporting(E_ALL);
$product = new Product();
$colour = new Colour('red');
echo get_class($colour).' ';
$product->setColour($colour);
echo $product->colour;
```

Comment: Thanks @pinouchon.

You're absolutely right, there aren't any problems!